# Prove that $(A^{-1})^n = (A^{n})^{-1}$ where $A$ is an invertible square matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I would like to prove following proposition:

> $$A^{-n} = (A^{n})^{-1}$$

Where $A^{-n}$ is defined as

> $$A^{-n} = (A^{-1})^n ,n \in \mathbb Z^{+}$$

I suppose mathematical induction will be the best shot. However, I would like to try different approach.

Given that 
$$A^{-n} = (A^{-1})^n$$

$(A^{-1})^n$ can be rewritten as

$$\tag1(A^{-1})^n = \underbrace{A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}...A^{-1}}_{n \text{ copies}} \implies $$

$$\tag2(A^{-1})^n = (A^{-1}A^{-1})\underbrace{A^{-1}A^{-1}...A^{-1}}_{n-2 \text{ copies}} $$

We know that $(A^2)^{-1}=(AA)^{-1} = A^{-1}A^{-1}$, hence $(2)$ can be rewritten as:

$$\tag3(A^{-1})^n = (A^2)^{-1}\underbrace{A^{-1}A^{-1}...A^{-1}}_{n-2 \text{ copies}} $$

Just to show that pattern emerges:

$$\tag4(A^{-1})^n = ((A^2)^{-1}A^{-1})\underbrace{A^{-1}...A^{-1}}_{n-3 \text{ copies}} \implies $$
$$\tag5(A^{-1})^n = (A^3)^{-1}\underbrace{A^{-1}...A^{-1}}_{n-3 \text{ copies}} $$

By repeating step above remaining $n-3$ times, we will arrive at:
$$(A^{-1})^n = (A^{n})^{-1}$$

$\Box$

---

I concede that the proof above might not be elegant as alternatives. But is it correct?

Comment: Your proof is fine ... as a conceptualization of a proof by induction. Indeed, getting rid of the informal "$\ldots$" and the "repeating step above" means to transform this into a formal proof by induction. -- On rechecking your proof: How do you know that e.g. $(A^2)^{-1}A^{-1}=(A^3)^{-1}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If my understanding is correct: We know that $(AA)^{-1} = A^{-1}A^{-1}$. Knowing this, we can infer that $(A^3)^{-1} = (A(A^2))^{-1} = (A^2)^{-1}A^{-1}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is it wrong?

Comment: To me it looks okay, but I think Hagen's concern is that if you're allowed to use $(AA)^{-1} = A^{-1}A^{-1}$, then what's stopping you from using directly $$(AAAA\ldots)^{-1} = \ldots A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}$$ ?

Comment: If your only goal is to avoid proof by induction then I would suggest to use that the inverse is unique. The result then follows by associativity of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @ganeshie8 Seems like nothing.

Comment: Haha then I guess your proof should be a one liner: $$(A^n)^{-1}=(AAAA\ldots)^{-1} = \ldots A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^n~~\blacksquare$$
may not make your profesor happy..

Comment: @ganeshie8 You're right...

Comment: This is a proof by induction, with extra steps

Comment: Hint: For any square matrix $B$, $B^{-1}$ is the unique matrix satisfying $BB^{-1} = I$, the identity matrix. Do you already know that, especially that the inverse is unique? If yes, you could try to use that: Show that both things are inverses of $A^n$, and thus conclude that they must be equal.

Answer (score 1):

The result needed to make the induction work is
$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$.